# ScrollDirection in iCarousel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I Am using `iCarousel framework`.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

**There I want to find out the swipe direction of a view**, because i am having next and previous actions, need to give for right and left scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know when the user scrolled the carousel and to know in which direction did she scroll. If so, you should implement the method

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel;
```

and compare the new index with the previous (stored) value - if the new one is greater than before, the user scrolled right, if it's smaller - scroll left.

Comment: @ Peter Sarnowski thanks for the reply, what happens if suppose im in 0th index (first card) and assume i have 10 cards and when user swipes back that time the 9th index 9>0 (newIndex>oldIndex) but user is scrolling left know??

Comment: Well, you would have to add two exception cases -> when oldIndex == 0 and oldIndex == itemCount and treat them appropriately. In all other, simple comparison will suffice.