# iCarousel scroll to one direction only through user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icarousel

I've implemented iCarousel in my app. I would like to have the iCarousel scroll by user iteration to one direction only.

My scenario is a list of views where the user can only go to the next one (the one to the right) by answering a question on the current view, so he can't go to the next one until he answers that. Once he answers, I'm programmatically scrolling to the next item . I still would like to have the users be able to scroll back previous views (to the left).

Right now I'm setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` so the user can't scroll at all.

I thought of doing something with `carouselWillBeginDragging:` and changing the `scrollEnabled` to `NO` depending of which direction he is scrolling, and set the `scrollEnabled` back to `YES` on `carouselDidEndDragging:`, but I couldn't figure out a reliable way of finding out which direction the user is scrolling.

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little google magic and it showed me the answer to your question.

If your question is "How to detect the the direction of the scroll?" well it was already answered

here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19090565/2301271)

**Edit::**

in `iCarousel.h` show `- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture;`

then create a subclass of iCarousel.

in the `iCarouselsubclass.m`:

```
-(void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture{
     // check direction here using values for super didPan method

     [super didPan:panGesture]; // do not call if you dont want to scroll the view
}
```

Comment: I don't think that answers my question. My question was about [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), not UIScrollView. iCarousel doesn't subclass UIScrollView, and I believe it implements it's own accelerating and decelerating mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had completely overlooked the carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange: delegate method while looking at the documentation. It helps identifying if it did scroll to the left or the right, but on my requirements I need to completely block the user from start scrolling to the right, while still allowing the left scroll.

Comment: @rantunes well I looked into the iCarousel class and didn't see any method that can provide what you need. For me the solution will be to show the didPan method then subclass iCarousel and override didPan

Comment: @rantunes i added an alternative if you really want to detect the before scrolling of iCarousel

Comment: Turns out I won't have to implement that feature anymore. I tried the same you suggested for a little Yesterday. It works when you are scrolling. The issue is, if the user scrolled a little to the left, I still wanted to have him have the ability to scroll back to the right until the initial position, but not past that. The problem is by moving that bit to the right, it accelerates the iCarousel. Once accelerated I would have to override also accelerate/decelerate methods to stop the scroll past initial point. I accepted your answer anyway because it's in the right direction tho. Thank you.